Legend is not reflecting symbol plotted in ggplot2
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
structure(list(season = c("Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter"
), effort = c(2559.85453311966, 4741.60449074074, 2014.4979040404, 
3429.23108974359), TotalVariance = c(211426.863838282, 726394.792895483, 
111303.839204525, 328799.605365902), STE = c(459.811770008426, 
852.287975331979, 333.622300220661, 573.410503362035), stocked = c(7089, 
17732, 0, 32902)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

I'm trying to plot these data using both a bar chart and a line graph but my legend is not using the right symbol for the line plotted:
coeff <- 10
plot <- c("Stocking"="#000000","Effort"="#d11141")
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = season)) +                                                         #Select data for plotting
  geom_bar(aes(y = effort, fill = "Effort"), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +                #Plot as bar chart, select position and color
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = effort-STE, ymax = effort+STE),
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.3, size = 0.8) +          #Plot error bars from data frame
  geom_line(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 5, shape = "diamond") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values = plot) + 
  scale_color_manual(name ="", values = plot) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated Effort (h)", expand = c(0, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .*coeff,
                                         name = "Number of Fish Stocked")) +        #Change y axis name and expand so bars touch y axis
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring','Summer')) +                #Order bars in order of seasons
  theme(legend.position = 'top')                                                    
      


How can I make it so the the black square in the legend represented stocking reflects the black line and diamond I plotted. Thanks!

With my actual set-up (R 4.3.2 and ggplot2 3.5.0) ; the plot and legends seems OK. Could you add details of your setup and/or the ggplot you got?  Here is a link of my rendered plot: (https://i.imgur.com/yx7GgKn.png)

Just added the output to the question, definitely does not have the symbol like yours does.

You might want to check/update your ggplot2 version:  https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0-legends/#awareness   .  Or as said it that blog, using guide_legend(override.aes) might work. I never did a two y-axis  ggplot, I don't have specific solution in mind.

Updated ggplot2 to 3.5 and that was the fix!

Some improvement were made with  legends in ggplot 3.5.0 , your code seems OK. Otherwise, you might want to use guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = "triangle"))) (example with triangle).
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df = structure(list(season = c("Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter"
), effort = c(2559.85453311966, 4741.60449074074, 2014.4979040404, 
              3429.23108974359), TotalVariance = c(211426.863838282, 726394.792895483, 
                                                   111303.839204525, 328799.605365902), STE = c(459.811770008426, 
                                                                                                852.287975331979, 333.622300220661, 573.410503362035), stocked = c(7089, 
                                                                                                                                                              17732, 0, 32902)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

# Plotting with ggplot2 3.5.0 seems  right
# https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0-legends/#awareness
coeff <- 10
plot <- c("Stocking"="#000000","Effort"="#d11141")
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = season)) +                                                         #Select data for plotting
  geom_bar(aes(y = effort, fill = "Effort"), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +                #Plot as bar chart, select position and color
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = effort-STE, ymax = effort+STE),
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.3, size = 0.8) +          #Plot error bars from data frame
  geom_line(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 5, shape = "diamond") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values = plot) + 
  scale_color_manual(name ="", values = plot) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated Effort (h)", expand = c(0, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .*coeff,
                                         name = "Number of Fish Stocked")) +        #Change y axis name and expand so bars touch y axis
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring','Summer')) +                #Order bars in order of seasons
  theme(legend.position = 'top') 
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: The `trans` argument of `sec_axis()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.5.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `transform` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.



# Manual ajustement withguide_legend(override.aes())  (before ggplot2 3.5.0)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = season)) +                                                         #Select data for plotting
  geom_bar(aes(y = effort, fill = "Effort"), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +                #Plot as bar chart, select position and color
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = effort-STE, ymax = effort+STE),
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.3, size = 0.8) +          #Plot error bars from data frame
  geom_line(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = stocked/ coeff, group = 1, color = "Stocking"), size = 5, shape = "diamond") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values = plot) + 
  scale_color_manual(name ="", values = plot) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated Effort (h)", expand = c(0, 0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .*coeff,
                                         name = "Number of Fish Stocked")) +        #Change y axis name and expand so bars touch y axis
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring','Summer')) +                #Order bars in order of seasons
  theme(legend.position = 'top') + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = "triangle")))


Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0
